# Interruption in android service

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android service that gets the location every so often and sends a notification. Despite the configuration that I do so that it does not optimize the battery in terminals Huawei and Xiaomi, in so oreo and foot I stop the service when I use the GPS of other apps or make phone calls. It also does not restart even when you have OnStarCommand () START_STICKY. Is there any way to restart this service automatically after these cuts? I have read that these brands have a very aggressive policy regarding battery saving, and I do not know if the shots go around.
Code notification:

```
private Notification getNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class);

    text = Utils.dameCoordenadas(mLocation);

    // Extra to help us figure out if we arrived in onStartCommand via the notification or not.
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);

    // The PendingIntent that leads to a call to onStartCommand() in this service.
    PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // The PendingIntent to launch activity.
    PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launch, getString(R.string.launch_activity),
                    activityPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_cancel, getString(R.string.remove_location_updates),
                    servicePendingIntent)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentTitle(Utils.dameTituloNotificacionLocalizacion(this))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker(text)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
    }

    return builder.build();}


 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Service started");
    boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION,
            false);
    if (startedFromNotification) {
        removeLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }
    return START_STICKY;}
```

Comment: whats you main problem? Do you have problem with device or api levels

Comment: Well I do not know if it's with the API or with the terminals. When I use the phone to call or receive a call, notifications are interrupted and the notification icon does not come out, although it tells me that the app is working in the background.

Comment: The main problem is that notifications are interrupted. Although the system tells me that the service is working, only with API >= oreo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here [Getting Location](https://github.com/BlackBlind567/Location_Updates-Background_Foreground) you can find the best code for location updates for oreo and above devices and it is working in all type of devices like mi, vivo and nokia.
Try this and any problem you have then mention in comments